# SpamAssassin: HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_XX

Tags: spamassassin

Spam Assassin is flagging my messages for the following violation:

> 1.6 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_24     BODY: HTML: images with 2000-2400 bytes of words

It seems to be telling me, literally, that:

- My message contains an image.
- My message only contains 2000-2400 bytes of words.
- These are typical attributes of spam.

My Question:

> Is the remedy for this problem to
>   simply add words? [Dare I say,
>   filler?]

Comment: If you're sending inappropriate pictures, be sure to include plenty of descriptive text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's flagging your message because the HTML version apparently contains an image, and the whole e-mail is only 2000 to 2400 bytes (which is pretty small). A piece of spam that contains just an image would appear like this.

The "solution" would be to add more words, specifically the e-mail size has to be over 3200 bytes to not be flagged by the set of HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_xx rules.

You seem to be really hung up on the fact that your e-mails fail a test here and there. It's really very normal for any given e-mail to fail a few tests. SA isn't a strict filter, it uses heuristic filters to determine spam likeliness.

Answer (score 0):

According to SA it's detecting an image with between 2000 and 2400 bytes of words in it. E.g. remove words from your images.

From the SA wiki:

> Explanation
>
> This may indicate a message using an image instead of words in order
>   to sidestep text-based filtering.